# while inserting the record into access db exception throw in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

iam trying to insert a record into ms-access database for that below code and method use

```
string SqlString = "Insert Into RegistrationForm (ClientCount,Name,Address,Contact,Documents,Money_Taking_Date,Muddat,Money_Return_date,Account_status,Taking_Amout,Interest_per_month,Pending_interest_month,Pending_interst_Amount,Total_Amount,Client_image,Document_image1,Document_image2) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            conv_photo();
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(SqlString))
            {

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ClientCount", lblcount.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox20.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", textBox21.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Contact", textBox19.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Documents", textBox18.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Money_Taking_Date", maskedTextBox1.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Muddat", textBox22.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Money_Return_date", maskedTextBox2.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Account_status", textBox23.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Taking_Amout", textBox17.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Interest_per_month", textBox16.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pending_interest_month", textBox15.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pending_interst_Amount", Convert.ToDouble(textBox13.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total_Amount", Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_image", pictureBox6);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Document_image1", pictureBox4);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Document_image2", pictureBox5);

                    conn.Open();
                    int n=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    if (n > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("record inserted");
                        loaddata();
                       // rno++;
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("insertion failed");
                }
            }
```

method conv_photo :

```
public void conv_photo()
         {
             //converting photo to binary data


             if (pictureBox6.Image != null)
             {
                 //using MemoryStream:
                 ms = new MemoryStream();
                 pictureBox6.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                 byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
                 ms.Position = 0;
                 ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictureBox6", photo_aray);
             }

             if (pictureBox4.Image != null)
             {
                 //using MemoryStream:
                 ms = new MemoryStream();
                 pictureBox4.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                 byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
                 ms.Position = 0;
                 ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictureBox4", photo_aray);
             }
             if (pictureBox5.Image != null)
             {
                 //using MemoryStream:
                 ms = new MemoryStream();
                 pictureBox5.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                 byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
                 ms.Position = 0;
                 ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictureBox5", photo_aray);
             }
```

now problem is when i run the application

Object reference not set to an instance of an object execption throw in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pictureBox6", photo_aray);` line

if i put conv_photo method after

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(SqlString))
            {

}
```

loop it giving me Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. execption (Argument exception waS unhandled)

not getting what should i do .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. You appear to be using two versions of `cmd`.  One seems to be global, since it is available inside of conv_photo, and the other is instantiated inside of wherever your top method is.  The global one is not being instantiated, at all (according to what you have displayed.)

Your using statement creates a brand new `cmd` object that has no relation to the one you're attempting to use inside of conv_photo.  Get rid of your global cmd object and put the call to conv_photo inside of your

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
```

and pass the `cmd` object into it, as an argument.

2. Your SqlString is NOT a connection string.  It is a SQL Statement.  You're going to need to look into what a [connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is, if you are unfamiliar.

Comment: Just to clarify a little for beginners; you need two different strings to interact with a data store from C#. The string that you pass to the constructor of your connection is a connection string. It is a string with some data in a specific format that instructs ADO.Net how to connect to your database. The string that you pass to the command should be a SQL statement. This is a string containing the SQL language statements to be executed against your database.